# Estimates with $L^n$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

this is my question:

Show that $\epsilon ||f||_{L^n(\Omega')}\leq \epsilon^{\frac{x}{n}}$, where $x$ is a positive number, using these two facts:

- $\int_{\Omega}|f|^x\leq C $
- $|f|\le\dfrac{C}{\epsilon}$  in  $\Omega'$

with $\Omega'$ subset of $\Omega$.

I think that the trick is something like Holder inequality, but i can't state something useful.

Comment: what is $x$ in $\varepsilon \|f\|\leq \varepsilon ^{x/n}$ ?

Comment: $x$ is a positive number, i am going to modify the question

Comment: This will mean that $\varepsilon \|f\|\leq 1$.

Comment: And what is $\Omega'$?

Comment: It's a subset of $\Omega$, i am going to modify my question

Comment: How are $n$ and $x$ related?

Comment: I don't know, there is only a Lemma without proof that says $x=x(n)$.